# Can only get NaN to return from simple Javascript form

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS so please be gentle.  What is going wrong with this code? I think I am getting the text from several fields, adding them together and showing the result.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function displaySum()
{
var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").text);
var number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").text);
var number3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number3").text);
var number4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number4").text);
var number5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number5").text);
var sum = eval(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5);

document.getElementById("showsum").innerHTML=sum;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
First Number: <input type="text' name="number1" id="number1" /><br />
<p id="numberOne"></p>
Second Number: <input type="text' name="number2" id="number2" /><br />
Third Number: <input type="text' name="number3" id="number3" /><br />
Fourth Number: <input type="text' name="number4" id="number4" /><br />
Fifth Number: <input type="text' name="number5" id="number5" /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="displaySum()">Display Sum</button>
<p id="showsum"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you say you're new, I'll be gentle: WHY THE HELL ARE YOU USING `eval`???

Comment: Also, if your parsing base 10, don't bother with parseInt. Multiplying a string by 1 will convert it to an int assuming base 10, even if it starts with a leading zero. (Unless it starts with `0x`, which makes it parse as hex.)

Comment: When you get an answer that "works beautifully", upvote it and accept it.

Comment: @Jcubed - No need to multiply. Just add a plus before it. Try pasting this into your console: `+"034"`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the `.text` property, you want `.value`. Also, use the second radix parameter to `parseInt()`, to guard against accidental incorrect parsing of octal numbers with leading zeros.

```
var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value, 10);
var number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value, 10);
// etc..

// Don't eval(), just add them.
var sum = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5;
```

[Here's the full solution in action](http://jsfiddle.net/DMc5s/) on jsFiddle.